# Creating Separate OnClick Listeners for Left and Right Navigation Drawers

Tags: android, android-xml, menuitem, android-menu

I currently have two navigation drawers/menus:

[image]

However I need a little bit of help setting up an OnClick listener for the right Action Bar menu.

Currently - I have an onclick listener for the left Action Bar Menu

```
   @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


            if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
                return true;
            }


            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
```

However I'm not sure how I might be able to handle an onClick event for the right Action Bar menu.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Full XML and Java Source:

http://pastebin.com/ygyyjtLZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
               case R.id.action_more: // change the action_more with your own id in main.xml menu
                 // do your stuff here (your right click method)
                 return true;
               // rest of your menu actions here...
           }
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
```

Comment: I tried the code you suggested - however when setting a breakpoint at  if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) { and clicking the right menu button - it is not reached when debugging :/ (which is strange - considering it is before the case statement)

Comment: Are you using a Fragment or Activity?

Comment: Activity - the full Java and XML source can  be found here: http://pastebin.com/ygyyjtLZ


(I appreciate your help - this is driving me nuts)

Comment: It's bizarre that I can't seem to register/listen for an onClick event on the right menu button... I really don't understand why this is.

Comment: Try to return *super.onCreateOptionsMenu()* instead of *true* ( in onCreateOptionsMenu() method )